# Implement Reverse SSH in linux

Tags: networking, ssh

I have to implement reverse SSH in Ubuntu. Can anybody tell me complete procedure of it.
I don't have any idea how to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think reverse ssh is already supported in openssh on ubuntu. why would need to implement it again ..